# Can the API return info re "new replies" icon?

Tags: support

I would like to be able to query the status of the "new mail" icon that shows whether there is new comments or favorites activity. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. The mail icon is for activity associated with a user login - things that have happened since they last visited with an authenticated machine. The API has no authentication - it's site centric, not user centric. Hence, this won't be possible until at least v2.0 (sometime next year).

Comment: Well, kinda. The API key is associated with the user who registered it, so it is feasible from a technical perspective (assuming no other dependencies like browser cookies are required), but because an API key can be shared among users, it doesn't make 100% sense from a usability perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you get the user timeline of an ID, which will give something very close to the new replies if not the same thing.

Comment: It's not *quite* the same thing :)

Comment: But it would be close enough until v2, wouldn't it?

Comment: I am looking for new replies since last read, so this wouldn't quite work for me...